# Copying the first line of a text file?

Tags: java, text, bufferedreader, filewriter

```
    for (int i = 0; i<file.length(); i++) { 
         while (line.charAt(i) != '\n') { 
          first = file.substring(0,i); 
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to get the code above to increment through the text, and if it finds a breakline, add that line to the instance variable first. I'm getting an out of bounds error for some reason.

I'm reading a text file using BufferedReader. I want to add the first line of the text file to an instance variable called line, and then pass it to a FileWriter which writes it into a new text file.

Also, another problem I have is, if I write the file to the new file, it adds it x amount of times (that the writer is called). How can I make it so it only writes this line only once?

Thank you.

EDIT:
The current FileWriter I'm using is writing multiple new lines to the new file. Say I add the line variable writer.write(line); it'll write

```
line
1
line
2
line
3

I want it like this:
line
1
2
3

static void file(String in) {
//nums is instance variable
String numbers = nums;
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(output,true);
            writer.write(line + System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n"));
            writer.write(numbers + System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n"));
            writer.close();
        }   catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a BufferedReader, just using readLine() works much more easily.

`String line = br.readLine();`

I'm not exactly sure what the second part of your question is asking. Can you clarify what the problem/usage is?

Comment: Could you post some code that shows where you're writing it?

Comment: Edited again! Also, readLine() worked for getting the first line!

Comment: hmm not sure. Try using a BufferedWriter - `BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);`, where `writer` is your FileWriter. You can then do `bw.write(line); bw.newLine(); bw.write(number); bw.newLine();`. And don't forget to `bw.close();` at the end of the try block. Give it a try and let me know! Glad to hear the readLine worked

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for the help, and the second one done the same thing as my code. Just with a newLine this time.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing the problem then. Could be with how you are calling the method `file`

Answer (score 1):

An explanation would be nice as pointed out by redFIVE. I am opening the file as an input stream and then reading all of its contents into a BufferReader (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). The BufferReader supports the function readline() which will handle all the messy hard work and let you access the file line by line. Lastly close the buffer to release and system resources.

```
private void readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    //Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       //do something with line
    }

    br.close();
}
```

Comment: You should explain what is happening instead of just dumping an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Scanner`. Something like that should do

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"))
line = in.nextLine();
```

The `in.nextLine()` reads up to `\n` and returns a string. If you want more lines you can use it in a while loop:

```
while(in.hasNextLine())
    line = in.nextLine();
```

etc..